# How to transpose the table in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, transpose

Table abc:

```
cookie_id   key         time
123         search      5/6/15
123         search      5/7/15
123         homepage    5/6/15
123         book        5/12/15
234         homepage    5/7/15
234         search      5/8/15
```

expected result as below :

```
cookie_id   homepage    search     book
123          5/6/15     
123                     5/6/15  
123                     5/7/15  
123                               5/12/15
234          5/7/15     
234                     5/8/15
```

how to make expected result table with tableabc????

Comment: Which `RDMS` you are using

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT 
    `Cookie_id`,
    (CASE WHEN `key` = 'homepage' THEN `time` END) AS `homepage`,
    (CASE WHEN `key` = 'search' THEN `time` END) AS `search`,
    (CASE WHEN `key` = 'book' THEN `time` END) AS `book`
FROM
    `tableabc`
```

Comment: Now its a duplicate of my answer :D

Answer (score 1):

Use `case` statement to get the desired result.

```
SELECT cookie_id,
       CASE WHEN key = 'search' THEN time ELSE NULL END as search, -- You can replace NULL with empty string
       CASE WHEN key = 'homepage' THEN time ELSE NULL END as homepage,
       CASE WHEN key = 'book' THEN time ELSE NULL END as book
FROM   Yourtable
```